# Check if a string is base64Encoded Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

How can I check if the string is base64 encoded in swift?

`Input = "tNC6umcfBS/gelbo2VJF3i4LAhUKMp4oDHWN5KyYUTWeJIQKKYx6oAcQnGncIrPJNC1tUYMKV4kJQj3q9voIOrxc1n7FmRFvDXeRgWGNcGYO66dH3VjoEgF0oxZOpfzwSZKSv3Jm7Q=="`

Comment: You can't really, you can check that it only use `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `+` and `/`, but there's no guarantee that such a string was actually intended to be base64. E.g. how do you know that `"apples"` means an encoding of binary `01101010 10011010 01100101 01111010`, and not just the plain English word apples?

Answer (score 3):

```
let base64Regex = "^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", base64Regex)
let result = predicate.evaluate(with: "InputString")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to decode using the built-in `Data`:

```
let inputString = "..."
let isBase64Encoded = Data(base64Encoded: inputString) != nil
```

Comment: Using Data(base64Encoded: inputString) will return nil if the input is numeric. However, Data(base64Encoded: inputString) validation will fail if the input string is "RA1000001475" which is not base64String.

Comment: @PabloDev - I don't get what you mean. why are you saying that "RA1000001475" isn't a valid base64? I checked in few online tools and it is a valid bas64